# She is his Keep

Tags: meaning-in-context, informal-language, indian-english

I do  not  know  how  this  usage  came  into India.I  have  searched  on google and  the  internet but  I  could  not find  the  usage.

> **She  is  his *keep*(concubine)**

I hear this usage in southern India  or  may  be  Andhrapradesh.

Is there any base for  such  a meaning In English  or  is it just  an Indian English?

Comment: In old fashioned UK usage you had such a thing as a 'kept woman', that is a woman entirely, or mainly, maintained financially , or provided with lodging at no charge (kept) by a man. A kept man is also possible.

Answer (score 2):

To "keep" something can mean "to protect, guard or care" for something.

> Farmer Giles keeps sheep on his farm.

In particular, when applied to a person, it means "to provide with housing and money"

> He kept a mistress for many years.

There is an old fashioned term "a kept woman" which means a woman who is dependent on a man who is not her husband. Usually a kept woman is a secret lover.

It is from this sense that the Indo-English term "keep" is derived. This usage is not standard in British or American dialects of English.